# Using SignaturePad in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, signaturepad

Does anyone has experience in using [SignaturePad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) in React?

I realise that the example is using DOM which I can try to replicate with Ref in react, but it doesn't seem very natural and I can't see any example online of using it in React.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to access DOM in react is using [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

You can either use `React.createRef()` or use React hooks with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Then you can call your ref to the canvas like this:

```
const myRef = useRef(null);

useEffect( () => { myRef.current.doSomething() });

return(
  <canvas ref={myRef}> </canvas>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a library that you want to integrate with React application then you can check out this [React Component Wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas) around *Signature Pad*. Hope this helps.